# What CAP-Type does Apache Accumulo have?

Tags: hadoop, accumulo, cap-theorem

During the evaluation of several distributed systems I came across the CAP-Theorem. Unfortunately I can't find a classification for Apache Accumulo.

Here is the actual question: What kind of cap-type is Apache Accumulo and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Accumulo is based on the Google BigTable paper, and shares a lot of similarities with Apache HBase. All three of these systems are intended to be CP, where nodes will simply go down rather than serve inconsistent data.